# How to seperate postitive and negative value from single column to different columns

Tags: sql-server

```
Account             Amount
------------       ..............
10101               5000
10012               6000
10101              -2000
10012              -9000
10101               2000
10012               7000
10101              -1000
10012              -1500
```

result must be like

```
Account            Positive_Amount         Negative_Amount
------------       ..............         ...................
10101               5000
10012               6000
10101                                     -2000
10012                                     -9000
10101               2000
10012               7000
10101                                     -1000
10012                                     -1500
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not complicated just use this query. I hope this help you:

```
--first add your new column--
ALTER TABLE Accounts
 ADD Negative_Amount decimal(10,2) NULL

--update your columns--
UPDATE Accounts
SET Negative_Amount = CASE WHEN Amount<0 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END
,Amount = CASE WHEN Amount>=0 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END

--this sp helps you to rename objects--
EXEC SP_RENAME 'Accounts.Amount' , 'Positive_Amount', 'COLUMN'
```

This is in case of when you want a structural change in your table. if you just want a result, other answers are the solution.

Comment: Be careful with this solution... you are changing the structure and all Front-End or report will need to be reviewed

Comment: u r right but as I can see in the question he did a structural change too in the "result must be like" part

Comment: I edited my answer and mentioned what you said. tnx @AngelM.

Comment: Good, yes, it is posible that matches if a new solución or want structural changes

Answer (score 4):

Very easy one with CASE clause:

```
SELECT Account,
       CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END AS Positive_Amount,
       CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN Amount ELSE NULL END AS Negative_Amount
FROM YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `CASE` could do it.

```
SELECT account, 
      (CASE WHEN Amount >= 0 THEN Amount ELSE Null END) AS Positive_Amount,
      (CASE WHEN Amount <  0 THEN Amount ELSE Null END) AS Negative_Amount
FROM tbl;
```